# Restoring Hyper-V VM without a Windows Server Backup

Tags: backup, hyper-v, vhd

I have a Hyper-V host that has a bad VM that I am trying to restore from a backup copy on the SAN.  I've copied over everything, created a new VM and attached the backup .vhd file but now Windows is in Startup Repair mode and asking for a Windows Server backup but it cant find one...

Is there anyway to restore a Hyper-V VM without a WSB image?

Comment: What OS is the VM?  How did you take the SAN backup?  Was it a simple LUN snapshot while the VM was running but without proper awareness inside the VM (quiesce)?  That's not really a good backup, as you need to use a product that quiesces the running VM so all data is written to disk first.  It's like ripping the HD out of a running server (or hard reboot).   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiesce

Comment: The VM is running Server 2008R2 Sp1.  The SAN did the backup using Veritas NetBackup so it wasnt even a LUN snapshot and I highly doubt that program has VM awareness.  It's a terrible backup as I am now just learning which is probably why it doesnt detect the WSB image inside the VM.

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen Server 2008 R2 ask for a Server Backup when booting so I'm not sure of your options at that point.  No idea what you have on that server but if it's your only backup then it sounds like you have two options:

- Boot into Windows recovery (F8) and attempt to repair what's broke (if F8 won't boot to WinRE then boot from DVD/ISO and choose recovery)
- Mount the .vhd to another working VM as a 2nd HD and pull your important data off and rebuild from scratch.